# How to make a node app route to different subdomains?

Tags: node.js, subdomain, openshift, paas

I use **OpenShift Paas**, I got a **`node.js`** application which got a custom domain. As  my site logic will got a general public web site, a blog site and an store site I want to have:

```
example.com
blog.example.com
store.example.com
```

About domain names this is not a problem, I got godaddy as domain name vendor and I simply added a CNAME record for general site. I think I will add proper aliases to same OpenShift domain name.

What I want so, is to make node within one only app attending each.

Being the JavaScript code about routes this:

```
self.createRoutes = function() {
        self.routes = { };

        self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
        };
    };


    /**
     *  Initialize the server (express) and create the routes and register
     *  the handlers.
     */
    self.initializeServer = function() {
        self.createRoutes();
        self.app = express();
        self.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
        for (var r in self.routes) {
            self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
        }
    };
```

Would the configuration be over there?

Would it be really necessary to have *another* app (node instance) even if it only will print `"Hello World!"`?

Comment: If you use express, then you can follow http://www.hacksparrow.com/vhost-in-express-js.html. the actual middleware code is only about 10 lines. But one thing, you can't host your website on your naked domain in OpenShift.

Comment: What about those `$ sudo vi /etc/hosts` changes? What would I use to change them?

Comment: those are for your own pc for testing, you do not need to do that since you need to point your dns cnames to OpenShift.

Comment: @wayne you can always provide a nice instructive answer :)